# How to generate python models from existing Postgres schema?

Tags: python, postgresql, migration, schema

I have a PostgreSQL database with existing tables. I wish to :

1. Create a set of Python models (plain classes, SQLAlchemy models or other) based on the existing database
2. Then manage changes in these models with a migrations tool.

The second part I think is easy to achieve as long as I manage to get my initial schema created. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Why build models at all? Use something like [Sqitch](https://sqitch.org/) and manage/migrate text SQL schema definitions. Eliminates the headaches an ORM creates.

Comment: What are the headaches ORM creates?

Comment: Extra layer of code. Essentially learning a new 'language' to interact with the database. ORM's try to be generic, but the underlying database's are not so either you get a non-performant generic solution or you have to figure what switches to toggle to get your case to work better. Extra overhead when working with data as it is encapsulated in an object or object like structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if someone is willing to use SQLAlchemy I found these two solutions:

1. Straight with SQLAlchemy [reflection and automapping](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/automap.html)
2. With [sqlacodegen](https://pypi.org/project/sqlacodegen/)